# Is Microsoft.Interop.Security.Azroles in Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, windows-server-2016, azman

The Authorization Manager (azman.msc) was deprecated for Windows Server 2012 R2, and it looks as though it might not be in Windows Server 2016.

But I can't find any information regarding Microsoft.Interop.Security.Azroles in Windows Server 2016. Where could I find information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Windows Server 2016 and just installed an application that comes with the Microsoft.Interop.Security.Azroles - library bundled. It worked fine.

azman.msc also still exists in Windows Server 2016.